# Appending values to a JSON key with terraform?

Tags: terraform, datadog

I am quite new to terraform. I have a provider that will accept JSON as input.
I have stored JSON config files in my project folder, eg:

```
{
    "id": 58187729,
    "name": "My dashboard",
    "tags": ["mytag1", "mytag2"]
}
```

and load them into the resource with the below code:

```
resource "datadog_monitor_json" "monitor_json" {
  for_each    = fileset(path.module, "/monitors/*.json")
  monitor = file("${path.module}/${each.key}")
}
```

Is there anyway I can easily append to the "tags" key or will the entire JSON need parsing somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, hardcoding stuff unless completely necessary is a bad idea, so you could work with local variables to add the tags to the JSON file and then later just add tags to that value instead of appending to JSON.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to add extra tags:

```
locals {
   example = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/myfile.json"))
   with_extra_tags = merge(local.example, 
                           {tags = concat(
                                   local.example["tags"],["mytag4", "mytag3"])})
}
```

gives:

```
test = {
  "id" = 58187729
  "name" = "My dashboard"
  "tags" = [
    "mytag1",
    "mytag2",
    "mytag4",
    "mytag3",
  ]
}
```